# Issue uploading data to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

**Hello!** and please don't be scared by my wall of text...

---

My engineering team and I are attempting to relate HTML/PHP to a MySQL database while using R programming to provide quick, graphical analysis to the website user.

*Synopsis of our idea:*

- Prompt user upload a .txt file of multiple receipts on website
- Upload said file to a pre-existing MySQL database
- Query & calculate useful statistics using R
- Display graphs and statistics of interest to the user

We've made a lot of progress on the R code and what we plan on calculating, however our main issue lies in the uploading of the data.

*The receipt files are all similar to this:

[image]

There are multiple files, each of which is around 20 MB in size. The dashes signify the start/end of a receipt with respect to the date.

---

**Our problem:**

With our current knowledge, the only way to account for the "---" delimiters is to use an if statement. Accounting for the varying length of the files, we're running a while loop until the end. These are both done in PHP. This allows us to hold the *'Retailer ID'* and the *'Date'* as variables for each line that *'Receipt ID'* and *'Price'* is found. Thereafter, we upload those 4 variables, line-by-line, into our MySQL database. We've decided to disregard the *'Tax'*, *'Total'*, and *'Payment Type'*.

For example, we want the first couple entries in our database to appear like this in order to query the data:

[Part of Receipt_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOIuU.png)

```
RetailerID | Date       | ProdID | Price
1          | 01/01/2014 | 79     | $7.93
1          | 01/01/2014 |  1     | $24.62
```

Clearly, this takes forever. It causes our website to have a fatal timeout error, one that we have no ability to change, so we've had to put a limit (cnt < 20000) in our loop just to get something into our database. It works for what we need, but not what we want given the receipt files are over 1,000,000 lines!

---

We've been exploring the usage of this SQL code:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' 
INTO TABLE Receipts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";
```

This successfully uploads the entire receipt, regardless of size, almost instantly. Still, we have no idea how to remove the dashes or iterate the *'Date'*/*'Retailer ID'* as variables unless we use a while loop. We want to cut that out completely as it slows our website down massively.

I think this would be an easier method, but all the technical resources online tend to be a bit over our heads. We've been exploring the usage of Java after reading up on a few of these, but again -- whooooooosh.

---

This is the first time we've worked with PHP and MySQL, so any nudge in the right direction would be great. There has to be a way to get rid of our deadly while loop!

Comment: This would be *considerably* easier if you did some pre-processing in PHP before smashing it into the database. At the very least, try re-writing it as valid CSV and import that. Even better, use a PDO statement with placeholders and run it against your data repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the multiple insert query in mysql. It allows you with one insert statement to insert a whole bunch of records. Much, much faster.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/

Answer (score 0):

You should do multiple inserts at the same time but not a massive one.

**Explaining myself :**

`Insert into blabla VALUES (), (), (), (), .... [x200 000]` = Very long for mysql

`Insert into blabla VALUES ()` [x200 000] = Very long

`Insert into blabla VALUES () [x100]` [x2000] = Faster

A very big transaction is long to process, a large number of small transactions too. So you have to do moderate transactions, but many of them. Work smarter, not harder :)

I hope its at least a bit clear ...